# What is the function of @tf_export before a tensorflow function definition in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working with Tensorflow in Python. In a custom written function I found `@tf_export()` before the function definition like below, the function of which I don't understand. Could somebody explain?

```py
@tf_export("signal.ifftshift")
def ifftshift(x, axes=None, name=None):
```

Answer (score 7):

As I understand, it allows Tensorflow to expose a function or class under a different name. For example, the [Server](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Server) class within the distribute module actually lives in the `training/server_lib.py` file within the repo, but, since it is exported as `distribute.Server`, you can use it like `tf.distribute.Server()`.

```
# training/server_lib.py
@tf_export("distribute.Server", v1=["distribute.Server", "train.Server"])
@deprecation.deprecated_endpoints("train.Server")
class Server(object):
  ...
```

It makes it confusing to find the code, but I imagine it's a more flexible way to create these "logical" modules.

Answer (score 1):

It is a convenient way to output **dot delimited** symbols directly to the `tf` API. Namely, a user can access `ifftshift()` with `tf.signal.ifftshift()`, without caring about the true path (here  `tf.python.ops.signal.fft_ops.ifftshif()`).